# ¿Qué significa 'liada' en este chat de WhatsApp?

Tags: verbos, significado, adjetivos, significado-en-contexto

A continuación se muestra una conversación entre un hombre y una mujer:

> **Ingrid**: Hola!
> Estoy bien!, gracias! Mis manos mejoran despacio . Y ha venido de visita un amigo de Barcelona que estará unos días, contenta con la compañía.
> Mañana aún no sé qué haré-haremos, hoy ya no lo hemos pensado, que pasó el día y estamos ya cansados, mañana veremos.
> Te cuento cuando sepa, si es posible vernos, si te apetece y puedes  juntarte al plan que hagamos… lo que sea te cuento.
>
> Buenas noche!
>
> **Ingrid**: Buenos días,
> Que tsl?
>
> Por aquí por la mañana vamos a estar haciendo cosillas. A la tarde aún no sé. Como tienes tu, la tarde?
> **Pedro**: Hola.
>
> **Pedro**: No tengo planes para tarde.
>
> **Pedro**: Te molesto demasiado, perdóname.
>
> **Ingrid**: hola! no, ninguna molestia, yo siento estar respondiendote tarde y poco!
>
> **Ingrid**: liadaaaaaa

Algo de contexto:
Se conocen de Tinder. Pedro quiere tener otra cita con ella. Ella es poliamorosa.

¿Qué significa ***[liada](https://dle.rae.es/liar?m=form)*** en este contexto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Liada = muy ocupada

Estoy liado = estoy muy ocupado